# how to convert form text input to ASCII in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

how to convert text input to ASCII and display in text area..

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Favorite Food</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fFood" placeholder="Favorite Food" required>
    <textarea name="txt_output"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It is not very clear what you're trying to do.  Please use words to describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you want to get the numeric ASCII codes, you should say that. Now the accepted answer shows (in the answer itself) only a way to show the content in a normal element, which is according to your comments not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you want mean is to display the "text" typed in `textBox` in `textArea`

If so, and here you go: [try here by clicking the button to display text in text area](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/LQ5Ly/6/)

The JS:

```
function display(){
var result = document.getElementById('fFood');
var txtArea = document.getElementById('textArea');
txtArea.value = result.value;
}
```

**EDIT** if you want to get the ASCII code from a string: [try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/LQ5Ly/7/).

[source of reference](http://networking.mydesigntool.com/viewtopic.php?tid=504&id=31)

Comment: I appreciate your response if user input in fFood "PIZZA" i need ASCII code in text area for input 'PIZZA"

Comment: Get the ASCII character code value of each letter and print each value with ' + ' next to it. After the last value print ' = ' next to it, and then print the sum of 

all the values.

Comment: I update the fiddle with convert `string` to `ascii` function. You can now print the ascii string inside the `textArea`. You might need to do the ascii sum by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is how do you get the character code of a character from a javascript string, then you would use the string method [`str.charCodeAt(index)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

```
var str = "abcd";
var code = str.charCodeAt(0);
```

This will technically be the unicode value of the character, but for regular ascii characters, that is the same value as the ascii value.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZLRZ7/

---

If what you mean is how you get the text out of a textarea field, you can do that by first getting the DOM object that represents that object and then by getting the text from that object:

```
var textareas = document.getElementsByName("txt_output");
var txt = textareas[0].value;
```

If you then want to put that text into the input field, you can do that with this additional line of code:

```
document.getElementById("fFood").value = txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(){
    var x = $('input[type=text]').val();
    $('textarea').val(x);
    });
});
```

javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById("fFood").value;
document.getElementById("ta").value=x;
}
</script>
```

and html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Favorite Food</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fFood" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Favorite Food">
    <textarea name="txt_output" id="ta"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: The convention here on SO is that you don't provide an answer in jQuery (or any other library) if there was no indication in the question that they are using or requesting that library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Ascii codes of the input string in the text area you can try this:

```
    var txtoutput = '';
var txtinput = document.getElementById('fFood').value;
for(let n=0;n<txtinput.length;n++)
txtoutput = txtoutput + txtinput.charAt(n) + ' -> ' +  txtinput.charCodeAt(n)+'\n';
document.getElementById('textArea').value = txtoutput;
```

This will show each character with its ascii code. Like: P -> 80 I -> 73 Z -> 90 Z -> 90 A -> 65